# Phone free RAM goes very low and apps crash

Tags: crashes, ram

My Xiaomi phone with 6Gb RAM is misbehaving. Every now and then free RAM goes as low as 500 Mb and apps, even those in the foreground crash.
Developer options don't seem to have a Memory option to see what is hogging RAM.
How do I find out what is causing the issue and solve the problem?

Comment: Self promotion: [How to free RAM on Android?](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/how_to_free_ram_in_android)

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [How much RAM should I allow an app to use, and how much should I always leave free?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/51643/44325)